# Как сделать автоматический input при запуске python скрипта?

Tags: python, консоль

[image: скрипта проверяет на powerOf2]

Как запустить код на терминале и сделать input автоматический,
также сохранить ответ где нибудь

Например:
input: 8
output: Yes

input: 8
output: Yes

input: 9
output: No

Comment: При чём тут [tag:django]?

Comment: Что означает *автоматический input*?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вы хотите, чтобы в a попало какое-то значение без ввода пользователем чего-то. Для этого нужно просто задать значение для переменной явно

```py
a = 8
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы при этом a при каждом запуске программы было разным, воспользуйтесь встроенной библиотекой random:

```py
from random import randint
a = randint(0, 100)
```

Такая конструкция будет каждый раз записывать в переменную `a` число от 0 до 100 включительно.

Сохранить ответ можно в файле, открыв его в режиме append, и добавляя при каждом запуске строчку нужного формата. Таким образом, полный код вашей программы мог бы выглядеть примерно так:

```py
from random import randint

def isPower0f2(n):
    return(n != 0 and (n & (n-1) == 0))

# Записываем в a случайное число от 0 до 100
a = randint(0, 100)

if isPower0f2(a):
    result = "Yes"
else:
    result = "No"
print(result)

# Записываем результат в файл
with open('result.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f'input: {a} output: {result}\n')
```

Answer (score -2):

Ну, "сохранить где-нибудь" -  это понятно. Сохранять что-либо на долго, точнее даже в случае отключения компьютера, вы можете на внешнем носителе. (Можно, правда, еще "где-нибудь" в сети. Но сильно подозреваю, что для вас пока это будет неподъемно).
А раз сохраняем на внешнем носителе - изучайте тему "Работа с файлами".

"запустить код на терминале" - (на самом деле, не "код", а "скрит", конечно) ну, например, вот так:

https://mkdev.me/posts/kak-zapustit-skript-na-python

Любая команда в скрипте, включая input, будет выполнена "автоматически" (думается мне, что имелось ввиду на самом деле "обязательно"), если, конечно, логика вашего кода не предусматривает другого.